# How to find the installation path of Windows OS using python?

Tags: python, windows, directory, operating-system

I wanted to get the installation path of operation system on Windows. For linux distribution, it would be `/home/{username}/`.
Is there a module to get this in python? Or we need to manually write a script for it?
Example:
I want : `C:/.../Users/{username}/Desktop/`
It's **C:**, I am interested in.

Comment: I found something that may be of interest for you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/138922/path-to-user-desktop-using-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you mean user path, not the installation path.

```
In [33]: import os

In [35]: os.path.expanduser('~')
Out[35]: 'C:\\Users\\john'
```

Comment: Great! Worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

1) Using [`os.environ`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.environ) to read the WINDIR environment variable:

```
>>> os.path.split(os.environ['WINDIR'])[0]
'C:\\'
```

2) Using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pathlib.html) to get the current user directory (Python 3.5+):

```
>>> pathlib.Path.home().drive
'C:'
```

3) Or a mix of both, because the user directory *could* be on a different drive:

```
>>> pathlib.Path(os.environ['WINDIR']).drive
'C:'
```

Comment: Precisely does what I needed. Thanks.